# Questions about scanner (BlueJ)

Tags: java, switch-statement, java.util.scanner

We have some guidelines for this task:
1. use scanner (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); )
2. use method scanner.nextLine()

we have to build a game (Mastermind) step by step and i always got an error (BlueJ) for using nextInt() with switchcase (for entering stuff that is not int)
btw: We shouldnt use nextInt - we should use nextLine - but how i can do this with switchcase?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Game {
/**
 * Methods
 */
public void play() {
    System.out.println("*******************  Game  **********************");
    System.out.println("* (1) CPU vs Human                              *");
    System.out.println("* (2) CPU vs CPU                                *");
    System.out.println("* (3) Human vs CPU                              *");
    System.out.println("* (4) Highscore                                 *");
    System.out.println("* (5) End                                       *");
    System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("Your choice:                                    ");

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    // i used this so far but i get an error for entering a-z or other stuff than numbers
    int userInput = scanner.nextInt();  

    //i have to use this but it doesnt work with switchcase - any suggestions?
    //String userInput = scanner.nextLine(); 

    scanner.close();
    switch(userInput) {
        case 1: // not written yet
        case 2: // not written yet
        case 3: // not written yet
        case 4: // not written yet
        case 5: System.exit(0);
        default: System.out.println("Illegal userinput! Only enter numbers between 1 and 5!");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please elaborate more.

Comment: like what? i use BlueJ for coding. We have tasks from our teacher and i dont know how to solve it correctly. Questions are written in the code. How do i use scanner.nextLine(); correct and how can i reenter a number after the errormessage "Illegal userinput! (...)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is to parse the string (which is yielded by the `.nextLine()` method) into an integer using the [`Integer.parseInt(String s)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) method. If the given string is not an integer, this method will throw a `NumberFormatException`, which you can catch and use to know when the user entered an invalid number so that you can ask him/her again.

Something like so:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    boolean validInput = false;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (!validInput)
    {
        System.out.println("*******************  Game  **********************");
        System.out.println("* (1) CPU vs Human                              *");
        System.out.println("* (2) CPU vs CPU                                *");
        System.out.println("* (3) Human vs CPU                              *");
        System.out.println("* (4) Highscore                                 *");
        System.out.println("* (5) End                                       *");
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Your choice:                                    ");

        try
        {

            // i used this so far but i get an error for entering a-z or other stuff than numbers
            int userInput = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine().trim());
            //If no error took place, then the input is valid.
            validInput = true;

            //i have to use this but it doesnt work with switchcase - any suggestions?
            //String userInput = scanner.nextLine();                 
            switch (userInput)
            {
                case 1: // not written yet
                case 2: // not written yet
                case 3: // not written yet
                case 4: // not written yet
                case 5:
                    System.exit(0);
                default:
                    validInput = false;
                    System.out.println("Illegal userinput! Only enter numbers between 1 and 5!");
            }
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid Input, please try again");
        }
    }
    scanner.close();
}
```

Comment: Can you please show / write what you exactly mean? I am not a java pro :) just started to learn it. Can you add a bit of code and show how you use the catch? Thanks by the way.

Comment: @JavaBeginner: Odd. Should be visible now.

Comment: thanks this works, but still there is a small error: if i enter 6 - the default system.out.println is used but after this i cannot enter a number again

Comment: It works!!! Oh Dude, you are awesome! Thank you so much. Sorry that i havent 15+ rep for vote up the answer - or can i "grant" you rep? you helped me so much. I work on a bit - perhaps i have another question later. How can i write you?

Comment: @JavaBeginner: You are very welcome. On the left hand side of each answer you can see a 'very good' mark. Clicking on that will mark the answer as correct and it will motivate others to answer your questions. 
If you have any further questions, just ask them on SO, **do not forget to include what did you try**.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly use the output of `nextLine()` for a switch-case, because `nextLine()` returns a String, not a char. However, if you are only reading in a single char, you can do:

```
String userInput = scanner.nextLine();
switch(userInput.charAt(0)) {
```

`scanner.nextInt()` will obviously throw an Exception if the next token is not parseable to an int. You should wrap these statements in try-catch block and do something appropriate if a non-number is entered.

Comment: i tried it like this and run it. entered 1 and: "Illegal userinput! (...)" and breaks - so the next question is - after this errormessage - how can i enter another number?

Comment: As of [Java 7](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk7/features/), you *can* switch on a String (the clauses would need to be `"1"`, `"2"` etc.). If you switch on a `char` the cases should be `'1'`, `'2'`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

`nextLine()` give you a `String`, and you should convert it to an integer (as it is what you expect) and perform subsequent logics.

Take a look in `Integer.parseInt()` method

Comment: done that but i have still the problem - can you help me a bit?

Comment: Be specific on the problem.

Comment: @JavaBeginner I have just tried and found no special problem on that.  Show us what you tried and the error you encountered

Comment: i tried it on my own but it didnt work - i deleted my code and tried the version below (npinti's) - but thank you so much for your efforts :)